# correlation peak and channel

Tags: digital-communications

I have 2 signals $s_1(t)$, $s_2(t)$. The magnitude of the autocorrelation functions verifies: $|R_{s_1}(\tau)|<|R_{s_2}(\tau)|$. But the amplitude difference is very small.

When the signals pass in the same channel (Rayleigh for example), I noticed that the relation was always verified. But if I transmitted these signals in the real world and more in simulation, will the relation remain true?

Comment: "Rayleigh for example": That doesn't help us answer your question. Of course, you could have a different channel which just always completely blocks one of the two signals. You will need to define which types of channels you want to consider! Otherwise, the answer is: no, without constraining your channel model, anything could happen.

Comment: Just to verify: $R_{s_1}(\tau)$ is the *autocorrelation* at delay $\tau$, right? and your statement is really that $|R_{s_1}(\tau)|$ is smaller than $|R_{s_2}(\tau)|$, for every $\tau$ in isolation, not just $\int_\mathbb R |R_{s_1}(\tau)|\,\mathrm d\tau<\int_\mathbb R |R_{s_1}(\tau)|\,\mathrm d\tau$?